# Doctrine ORM Not Updating Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

Here's my code:

```
        $data = $eManager->getRepository('Entity')->findOneBy(array('user_id' => $id));
        $data->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
        $eManager->persist($data);        
        $eManager->flush();
```

Here's things I know:

- The $data object is returned from the DB correctly
- The $data object returned correctly formatted
- I've tried "merge" instead of "persist"... no good
- The setUpdatedAt method works
- I've tried adding "$eManager->commit();" as well, no good
- The code throws no errors
- My entity, in another method, is being created correctly. So the Entity class and database connections are working

But it's not actually persisting to the database.

I'm new to Zend/Doctrine/Apigility... is there anything else I need to check to make sure that the data is persisting? All the documentation seems point to this as the desired method but I can't figure out why it's not persisting to database.

Comment: Try var_dump ing the data before you flush it. Do you see the value actually updated?

Comment: Yes - the $data object is actually updated.

Comment: You don't need the `persist()`-call at all, as the object is already managed. But it shouldn't do any harm though... Try looking at the symfony2 profiler. There you can see all executed queries. Maybe that sheds some light onto the problem

Comment: Neither persist nor merge is needed for updates.  Just changing the object and flushing is all you need to do.  Have you messed with the change detection strategy at all?  Dates can be a bit tricky as they are assigned by reference.  Maybe post your setUpdatedAt method.  And maybe try updating a different type of attribute.  And of course make sure you are looking at the correct table when you checked to see if it worked.

Comment: @EmanuelOster Thanks for the help. Removing persist didn't work (though it shouldn't have hurt) and I'll look into the symfony2 profiler

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for the info. Removing persist didn't work and I'm sure that any other attributes that I've attempted to update with the same methodology (name, description) aren't working either. I'll look into the change detection strategy, thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Methods for the win.

As I mentioned I am using Zend/Doctrine and Apigility. The answer to this was that the code was correct but the middle layer of Apigility was doing something being the scenes to filter out the request based on the HTTP method. Not sure exactly what as I'm still getting used to this framework but once I moved the code from the update() method to the patch() method it worked.

I considered deleting the question since the doctrine part of it was correct but for anyone who might be using both Doctrine and Apigility, this might be helpful.

Comment: I think deleting the question would be a better option here, since the whole 'update' method you mention in your answer was never mentioned in your question.